PMDC motor stops spinning when speeding up with pedal
I am driving a PMDC motor with a half bridge circuit in which the low side MOSFET is a freewheel diode and it is always at "on" stage. I am only switching with the high side MOSFET via an IR2110 drive circuit. When speeding up (PWM duty cycle increasing), the motor terminal voltage is strange looking and after getting to 50-55 % duty cycle the motor stops running. Every time I start the circuit the same behavior occurs. I am sharing oscilloscope pictures which different PWM duty cycle stages of motor terminal. I think the problem can be a low side MOSFET body diode speed or bootstrap capacitor having a hard time with charge-discharge I don't know, I am sure that the control signals are good.
Sorry for bad pictures, At the oscilloscope screen voltage level is 0-48 V since battery voltage is 48 V nominal. P4 and P5 corresponds the motor connection.
NOTE: I am not sure but when I connect my motor to load shut down problem solved but still same waveform observed. The only reason comes to the my mind is energy in the motor will start to discharge with torque (current draw) and inductance of motors not saturate and don't stops to rotate. Still I need approval.
NOTE 2: Now I change motor connection low side to high side for I am sharing the picture of new schematic.

With this change I am controlling low side MOSFET and keep closed the high side MOSFET problem solved same waveform observed but I think there is no problem with waveform I share at the top pictures. The problem I think is B-EMF of motor is cause a high side switching problem after some speed level. For observation and clearer answer I am gonna share the Vs voltage to see what is going on.




Below image is resistive load waveform of output:


You'll need to post a larger part of the circuit diagram.  It should include the driving circuit for the MOSFET gates.

I adding the part of Gate Drive circuit.

the low side MOSFET is a freewheel diode and it is always at "on" stage. What voltage should I expect at P4? 0 V with SW1 off, $V_{CC}/2$ with SW1 on?

I expect this behaivour from circuit 0V when SW1 on, and VCC (48V) when SW1 is off. But In the pictures I share in the SW1 on state voltage is 0 at start of SW1 ON state period after a short time voltage is 18-20V its always increasing with duty cycle getting bigger. Measurements maded with P4-P5 terminals.

With SW2 always on, you get a shoot through whenever SW1 turns on. (I recommend testing with a load resistor - 1 kΩ, 10 W to GND?)

With load resistor values 30 ohm, I edited the question with oscilloscope picture.

The screen shots look relative OK to me. Between the MOSFET pulses we see the motor back EMF, higher at larger duty cycle as expected. So what do you see if the motor stops? Does the supply turn off because a mosfet shoot through occurs?

Without load motor stops %50-%55 duty, when exceed this value motor voltage slowly drops to 0V and motor coast and stop after reach 0V terminal. And I can't give energy to motor unless motor voltage reach a 0V while this behaivour happens(i need to wait for discharge i guess and its unwanted in my application). This %50 exceed value is increase to %80 when I connect motor to gearsystem and motor start to draw little bit more current from first condition(effect of inertia). And this "wait for motor voltage drop to 0V problem" is happens if i try to for example change duty to %70 to %40 fastly).

(Don't comment comments asking for clarification or complementary information: edit the post.) Please show the control signal for SW2 (TP6 or U6 terminal LO or Lin) - multichannel oscillogram welcome.

Can you post an oscillogram of Vb, Vs and HO?

when I connect my motor to load [this motor controller power stage, the] shut down problem [looks] solved…
Without a current sink/a non-high impedance path from \$V_S\$ to GND, the bootstrap capacitor does not get charged sufficiently.
Wild guess:
While the current through the motor is discontinuous, the time/voltage to charge C27 is insufficient due to \$V_S\$ rising to the "coasting voltage" of the motor.
Try connecting two additional Schottky diodes' anodes to \$V_S\$, one cathode to P4, the other to a 25 Ωish resistor to U6 terminal LO.
(Will probably not work to really high duty cycles. You can try to connect C27 to 20 V rather than 12 V.)
…but still same waveform observed
I don't see that in the oscillogram showing time base and voltage scale.
Comparing to the others, one outside explanation for the different "SW1-off-level voltages" - about 9 V in the uppermost one, 18 V in the second, 38 V in the third? - would be that is the voltage generated by the motor.
But that should be just 48 V * duty cycle, which seems to be about 5, 10, and 40 %.
I notice that the first digit where there is the 2 of 25.46 kHz in the big one reads 7 in the first two oscillograms:
you may be varying on-time, not duty cycle.

I don't know but sometimes frequency value written in screen is not correct for example when i stop signal and measure period with calculations frequency always same. I guess nothing wrong about Frequency.

You mentioned you didn't see oscilogram. Its because of I put resistance at output of motor controller. When I connect motor itself, same waveform observed.

didn't see oscilogram I don't see [same waveform as in 1-3] in the [last] oscillogram. Please edit the question to be as clear as possible.
